# How do I get activated plugin list in wordpress plugin development?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, codex

Is there any way to get all **activated plugin list** in **wordpress codex** .

i used this

```
get_option('active_plugins');
```

this return the plugin file path. I want the name. Because sometimes file name is different with the actual plugin name.

Comment: Hi, please always remember to Google first. A query for `wordpress get list of active plugins` gives a full answer. There is no need to start a new SO question for it.

Comment: See e.g. [How to do I get a list of active plugins on my wordpress blog programmatically?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/54742)

Comment: @Pekka웃 Please read the description. I modified something in description.

Comment: @Pekka웃 - Searching for "codex list of activated plugins" brings me right here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I got the answer

```
$apl=get_option('active_plugins');
$plugins=get_plugins();
$activated_plugins=array();
foreach ($apl as $p){           
    if(isset($plugins[$p])){
         array_push($activated_plugins, $plugins[$p]);
    }           
}
//This is the $activated_plugins information
```

Comment: `get_plugins()` needs a `require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/plugin.php');` or you'll get a Fatal Error calling it in the front end.