# Find action from one plugin to another plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I am developing plugin that is depend on another plugin, my issue is  I want to track actions in my plugin that is defined in another plugin. so please suggest me how can I do this

Comment: complicate. The simplest way is to search the actions manually. You can print out all actions but the list is very long (inclusive Core actions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check another plugin is activated or not with this conditions.

Add following code into your plugin where you want to check.

```
$plugin = 'Another-Plugin-Name'; //The name of the plugin sub-directory/file. 
if( is_plugin_active($plugin) )
{
    //add you action or whatever...
}
```

Hope it help.

Answer (score 0):

You could try scanning the plugins folder and retrieving the meta data for each plugin using  get_plugin_data

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_plugin_data

Or you could parse the get_option('active_plugins') feed as seen here:

[How do I get activated plugin list in wordpress plugin development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20488264/how-do-i-get-activated-plugin-list-in-wordpress-plugin-development)