# get list of activate plugin in wordpress and remove plugin link from admin menu

Tags: php, wordpress

Is it possible to get activate plugin list in wordpress and remove it from admin menu bar ?. i want to remove all activate plugin links  from adminu bar .

Comment: You mean the navbar at the top, or the side bar on the left, or the Plugins page?

Comment: @jordandap I have edited my answer, that may help you more to reach to solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get activated plugin list in wordpress plugin development?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20488264/how-do-i-get-activated-plugin-list-in-wordpress-plugin-development)

Answer (score 2):

Findout the page and replace `your_plugin_page` .

```
<?php
function remove_menus(){

  remove_menu_page( 'your_plugin_page.php' );  //probably where the plugin settings are available
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'remove_menus' );
?>
```

This will list out all activated plugins:-

```
  $apl=get_option('active_plugins');
    $plugins=get_plugins();
    $activated_plugins=array();
    foreach ($apl as $p){           
        if(isset($plugins[$p])){
             array_push($activated_plugins, $plugins[$p]);
        }           
    }
```

now you need to get all the pages .Not a perfect solution , but I hope it will be helpful.